# Change in order of integration for iterated integrals.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $dx$ be the lebesgue measure then the following iterated integral makes sense. $$I=\int_{L^1(\mathbb R)}\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}|u(x)-u(y)| dy\ dx\ d\mu(u)$$

But then tonneli theorem says the order can be changed so we have $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)}\int_{L^1(\mathbb R)}|u(x)-u(y)|d\mu(u)\ dy\ dx=I$. But my confusion is why this integral $ \int_{L^1(\mathbb R)}|u(x)-u(y)|d\mu(u)$ makes sense?

Comment: Indeed it does not make sense. What do you mean by $d\mu(u)$? If $u$ is a function, you can't integrate with respect to a function.

Comment: $\mu$ here is a probability measure on $L^1$. My question is  tonneli says $\int||u||_1d\mu(u)=\int\int|u(x)|d\mu(u)\ dx$ then how the second integral is defined?

Comment: If it's not making sense then I can't justify the use of tonneli theorem.

Comment: What sigma algebra are you using on $L^1$? Note that for Tonellis theorem, you need to know that the integrand is measurable (and well defined). I think at least one of these properties will fail here. Note that evaluating an $L^1$ function pointwise does not make sense.

Comment: Cylindrical sigma algebra is used but I see later that it's same as the borel sigma algebra.